# VUE3 properties from root component not visible in child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

Guys sorry if is dump question am learing VUE3 and befeore i post this question i research google and not found result.

I want to define global property in Root Component that will be used in all child properties. Property like BASE_URL link or TITLE.

**Here is my Root Component**

```
<script>
    import HeaderTop from './pages/partials/header_top.vue'
    import HeaderMiddle from './pages/partials/header_middle.vue'
    import MainNavbar from './pages/partials/main_navbar.vue'
    import MainFooter from './pages/partials/footer.vue'

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                show: true,
                baseURL: 'www.example.com' 
            }
        },

        mounted() {
            this.show = true;
        },

        components: {
            HeaderTop,
            HeaderMiddle,
            MainNavbar,
            MainFooter
        }
    }
</script>
<template>...</template>
```

**HeaderMiddle.vue component**

Here i want to call property from RootComponent

```
<script>
    import app from '../../RootComponent.vue';

    export default {
       
       // i also try this ant this not work
       data() {
        return {
            baseURL: app.baseURL
        }
       }
    }
</script>
<template> 
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row text-center align-items-center height-150">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-2">
            <div class="logo">
            <a href="/" title="">

                <h1>{{baseURL}}</h1>  <!-- not work -->
                <h1>{{app.baseURL}}</h1> <!-- not work -->
                <h1>{{app.baseURL}}</h1> <!-- not work -->

            </a>
            </div>
        </div>
     
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

**App.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');

import { createApp } from 'vue';
import router from './router'
import RootComponent from './RootComponent.vue'
 
const app = createApp(RootComponent);
 
app.use(router).mount("#app");
```

Comment: Hi Ivan! This seems like it would be a good use case for the provide/inject mechanic offered by Vue. Look up [Provide / Inject | Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html) Basically, you can provide whatever you need in your root component and inject the value into any child you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's recommended to provide `baseUrl` as [global property](https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-config-globalproperties) :

```js
require('./bootstrap');

import { createApp } from 'vue';
import router from './router'
import RootComponent from './RootComponent.vue'
 
const app = createApp(RootComponent);
app.config.globalProperties.baseUrl='www.example.com'  
app.use(router).mount("#app");
```

and use it inside any child component like :

```html
<script>
   export default {
       data() {
        return {
            baseURL: this.baseURL
        }
       }
    }
</script>
<template> 
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row text-center align-items-center height-150">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-2">
            <div class="logo">
            <a href="/" title="">

                <h1>{{baseURL}}</h1> 

            </a>
            </div>
        </div>
     
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

Comment: Mr.Boussadjra Brahim thanks this is second good solution after props/inject method. I try this and work good. By the way in child component i not declare new baseURL propert just only in app.js and work well.

Comment: your'e welcome, this is better than props/inject since it doesn't require declaration option in child component, `baseURL: this.baseURL` is not needed, please don't forget to upvote my answer

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when we need to pass data from the parent to a child component, we use props. However, imagine the case where we have a large component tree, and a deeply nested component needs something from a distant ancestor component. With only props, we would have to pass the same prop across the entire parent chain. But we can use Props drilling to deepchild.

Props drilling with `provide` and `inject`.

`**PROVIDE**` - A parent component can serve as a dependency provider for all its descendants

Example Provide:

```
export default {
  provide: {
    message: 'hello!'
  }
}
```

Example Inject:

```
export default {
  inject: ['message'],
  created() {
    console.log(this.message) // injected value
  }
}
```

You can check more details from [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html#working-with-reactivity)